# Sbt 0.13 to 1.0 - What's the replacement for onLoad in Global for multiprojects?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to create a new project, this time with sbt 1.0.2 instead of 0.13.x which I used for quite some time now.

There I had a multi-project setup comparable to https://github.com/vmunier/akka-http-with-scalajs-example/blob/master/build.sbt

My problem now is that I *always* get `[error] (projectname/compile:bgRun) No main class detected.` when I try to run `sbt run`

Here is my current `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val generalSettings = Seq(
  name := "awesomeproject.tld",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
)

lazy val client = (project in file("modules/client"))
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "client",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.6.5",
      "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.2"
    )
    , scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
  )
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSWeb)
  .dependsOn(sharedJS)

lazy val server = (project in file("modules/server"))
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "server",
    scalaJSProjects := Seq(client),
    pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline),
    // triggers scalaJSPipeline when using compile or continuous compilation
    //compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalaJSPipeline).value,
    WebKeys.packagePrefix in Assets := "public/",
    //managedClasspath in Runtime += (packageBin in Assets).value,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.4" % Test,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.4",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.5.4" % Test,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.10",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.0.10" % Test,

      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
      "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2",

      "com.lihaoyi" %% "scalatags" % "0.6.5",
      "com.vmunier" %% "scalajs-scripts" % "1.1.0"
    )

    , mainClass := Some("tld.awesomeproject.Main")
  )
  .dependsOn(sharedJVM)

lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("modules/shared"))
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "shared"
  )

lazy val sharedJS = shared.js
lazy val sharedJVM = shared.jvm
```

As you can see I tried to solve the problem with setting it explicitly with `mainClass := Some("tld.awesomeproject.Main")` in the subproject. I also tried to set a root project explicitly, make it dependOn the server but no luck.

I guess the real problem here is, that

`onLoad in Global := (Command.command("project server", _: State)) compose (onLoad in Global)` does not work in sbt 1.0.2 anymore.

I checked the `Command` class, but I am not wiser after. There simply is no more method that gives back a state.

Can anyone shed like on this? What I want is to run a server that sends some javascript to the client... that shouldn't be black magic, in fact everything worked like a charm in my 0.13. project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
onLoad in Global ~= (_ andThen ("project server" :: _))
```

Reference: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1224#issuecomment-331840364